# Чи дійсно є різниця між управлінням та керуванням?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Як відомо [зі словників української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53402/31083.html), різниця між цими словами дійсно є. Можна керувати транспортним засобом чи приладом, проте управляти групою людей чи установою. Щось типу manage, lead, control, maintain

З іншого боку ми маємо одну з галузей системного аналізу, яку частіше перекладають та викладають як "теорію керування". Хотілося б дізнатися про повсякденний вжиток слів та їхню взаємозамінність. Чи буде критичною помилкою вживати одне слово замість іншого? Бо я, наприклад, вживаю згідно встановлених вище правил, інколи реагую, коли не дотримуються цього співрозмовники, проте може то я помиляюсь?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Мабуть, Ви не чекали на таку відповідь.

### «Керувати» й «управляти» — чим?

Згідно з [тим самим посиланням](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53402/31083.html), що Ви надали:

- «керувати» можна:

  - і «транспортним засобом чи приладом»:

    > спрямовувати рух, хід, роботу чогось за допомогою керма та інших пристроїв
  - і «групою людей чи установою»:

    > бути на чолі когось, чогось, давати вказівки, бути керівником установи
- «управляти» також можна:

  - і «транспортним засобом чи приладом»:

    > кермом та іншими пристроями – рідше
  - і «групою людей чи установою»:

    > те саме, що керувати […]: управляти підприємством.

Хоча словник за посиланням, що Ви надали, каже, що «управляти» до транспортних засобів і приладів застосовуються рідко. Але: по-перше, те, що застосовується рідко, не означає, що це заборонено; по-друге, не всі словники поділяють думку, що це рідко, наприклад, СУМ-11 зазначає це значення для цього слова без помітки «рідко».

Висновок:

- «керувати» — універсальне слово;
- «управляти» — *бажаніше* застосовувати до людей чи установи, але *можна* й у інших випадках.

### «Керування» й «управління» — чим?

Це може здаватися неочевидним, але не завжди іменник, утворений від дієслова наслідує значення всіх дій, для яких може застосовуватися дієслово.

Подивимось:

- Згідно з СУМ-11, [керування](http://sum.in.ua/s/keruvannja) позначає дію за 1-им і 2-им значеннями слова [керувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/keruvaty), тобто може застосовуватися і до автівок/приладів, і до людей/колективів — універсальне слово в плані позначення дії (але не самих керівників, самого органу чи інформаційних матеріалів — але не про них мова).
- Згідно з СУМ-11, [управління](http://sum.in.ua/s/upravlinnja) позначає дію лише за значенням `2.1` слова [управляти](http://sum.in.ua/s/upravljaty), тобто може застосовуватися **лише до людей/колективів** (якщо вірити, що «управляти» рідко застосовується до автівок/приладів, то не дивно, що «управління» могло успадкувати лише більш поширене значення).
- Згідно зі словником за Вашим посиланням, [керування](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53402/31081.html) позначає «спрямування руху, ходу, роботи чогось за допомогою керма та інших пристроїв» — щодо застосовності до автівок/приладів сумнівів не виникає — а також «керівна дія в межах системи, […]; безпосереднє керівництво оркестром, хором тощо: […], керування промисловістю, керування ансамблем» — виглядає так, що наче до колективів теж можна (хоч і не факт, що можна до окремих людей).
- Згідно зі словником за Вашим посиланням, [управління](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53411/32536.html) — це або те саме, що 1-е значення керівництва, тобто дію стосовно людей, або *зрідка* те саме, що 1-е значення керування, тобто дію по відношенню, як мінімум, до автівок/приладів і колективів.

Висновки:

- «керування» може застосовуватися, як мінімум, до автівок/приладів і колективів, а також, можливо, й до окремих людей;
- «управління» може застосовуватися, як мінімум, до людей/колективів, а також, можливо, *зрідка* до автівок/приладів.

### Теорія керування

[Теорія керування](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) в рамках системного аналізу стосується в загальному випадку керування будь-якими системами об'єктів, але здебільшого все ж фізичними, а не людськими. З цієї точки зору слово «керування» підходить, а «управління», враховуючи рідкість його застосування до фізичних систем, — менше.

Є ще один аспект. Хоча це не випливає безпосередньо з якихось словникових статей, але після читання статей вище і особистого досвіду в мене складається враження, що управління має відтінок більш високого рівня. Тобто керувати можна як безпосередньо, так і, перебуваючи на верхніх рівнях системи, через проміжні ланки — а от управління, принаймні людьми, частіше означає управління високо згори. Мовляв, управління ближче до значення слова «правити» («переважно здійснювати верховну владу над ким-, чим-небудь»); за Вашим посиланням «управління» може означати 1-е значення «керівництва» («переважно спрямування діяльності людей, під проводом яких, на чолі з якими здійснюється діяльність певного колективу; загальне відання»). До теорії керування, відповідно, така зверхність зовсім не підходить, бо теорія керування в тому числі вивчає математичні моделі, що дозволяють *безпосередньо* направляти поведінку об'єкта, *неперервно* регулюючи його числові показники. Теорія керування — це *не* про топ-менеджмент (чи принаймні не лише про нього).

### Не як дія

Хоча ті значення слів «керування» і «управління», що позначають дії, не так легко розрізнити, тим не менш в них є інші значення, які відрізняються кардинально.

Наприклад:

- У слова «управління» є значення «орган/компанія/товариство, що управляє». Наприклад, Ви можете зателефонувати в *управління* у справах сім'ї, дітей та молоді. А в *керування* Ви зателефонувати чи надіслати листа ніяк не зможете (хоча можете, наприклад, *керівництву*).
- Зате в словосполученні чи реченні одне слово може *керувати* іншим. Наприклад, в попередньому реченні слово «керувати» *керує* словом «інший» — і це називається дієслівне *керування*. Але воно не *управляє* ним і не можна казати про дієслівне *(у)правління*.
- Згідно з СУМ-11, «керівництво» також може позначати «те, чим керуються», наприклад: «Різні пристосування, якими користуються герої К. Е. Ціолковського, щоб поліпшити умови перебування в середині ракети, теж можуть стати практичним керівництвом для конструкторів.» Хоча останнім часом відходять від того, щоб перекладати «руководство пользователя» як «керівництво користувача» (посібник, інструкція, порадник) і, можливо, «практичне керівництво» теж скоро відійде в минуле (настанова).

### Висновок

Слова «керувати» і «управляти» (а також «керування» і «управління») мають дуже багато спільного. Є й певні відтінки значень чи навіть окремі значення. Тим не менш, різниця не така проста й прямолінійна, як Ви написали. Якщо у фразі: «можна керувати транспортним засобом чи приладом, проте управляти групою людей чи установою» — Ви мали на увазі «лише так», то це просто неправильно.

Величина помилки при заміні одного слова на інше, очевидно, залежить від ситуації, в якій зроблена заміна. Оскільки слова дуже близькі, то здебільшого помилки не буде чи вона буде мінімальною. Але, знов таки, це залежить від конкретної ситуації. (Іноді помилка може бути грубою.)

Слово «керівництво» стоїть трішки далі від «керування» й «управління». Хоча воно теж може позначати саму дію, але воно стосується *лише* людей (також колись «керівництво» могло означати «настанову»). «Правити» і «правління» також стоять трішки окремо, маючи конотацію керування високого рівня у випадку людей — хоча «правити» (але не «правління») іноді може застосовуватися і до механізмів.

Answer (score 1):

Керівник таки керує людьми і скеровує їх у вірному напрямку. Керівництво (установи) також є загальновживаним терміном.

Comment: -1: Це більше схоже на коментар, аніж на відповідь на запитання.

Comment: @bytebuster Задане запитання починає з невірних посилань, що по відношенню до людей - управління, а не керування. Як то кажуть на Кворі, якщо питають "чому", перша відповідь має бути "чи справді".